# как отправить пакет от чужого приложения?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, winsock

Есть онлайн игра написанная на дельфи. Хочу написать что-то вроде трейнера.Инжектил в нее свою Dll. Узнавал дескриптор сокета и по нажатию клавиш отсылал нужные мне пакеты, но GetAsyncKeyState создавал луп и в итоге огромная нагрузка на проц и приложение крашилось. Как можно иначе?
Возможно ли как то с помощью writeprocessmemory прописать в стек данные свои и отправить от приложения?

[image: ws2_32.send]

Comment: Можно. Если в двух словах - записывать данные можно в любое свободное место. Отправлять - запуская стандартную функцию игры по отправке данных. Она обычно принимает адрес и размер отправляемых данных. Но эту функцию вам придется искать

Comment: то что на скрине,не то?

Comment: То что на скрине это вызов WSA если данные не нуждаются в подготовке(шифрование/сжатие/....) то вы можете так же устанавливать регистры и вызывать WSA инекцией кода и данных.... и не забывайте чистить за собой

Comment: я поставил брейкпоинт на Data..отправка пакета происходит намного после чем вызов функции которая на скрине.я думал записать данные в память,дальше в дату что на скрине и дальше просто вызвать функцию отправки,но не знаю как вызывать ее через свою программу)данные прописать не проблема,а вот как отправить(просто вызвать функцию),гугл не помог мне)

Comment: `отправка пакета происходит намного после чем вызов функции` возможно следствие использования алгоритма нагла. `но не знаю как вызывать` написать код который поместит нужные значения по регистрам(адрес\размер\сокет\...) и дальше разместить этот код в памяти чужого процесса, таким же способом как и данные, а потом вызвать `CreateRemoteThread`